# How to safely try to perform segue in Swift while ignoring/handling manually possible exceptions?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to make a custom view controller for use in my projects, that has possible 3 segues from it. But those are not mandatory. 
When view controller loads i'm calling a method "`trySegues()`" that should try to perform all 3 of those segues. Segues are custom, so each successful call will be handled and registered in my code.

In Objective-C i would do that using "`@try` - `@catch`" so all the successful calls will go forward, while if one of those segues is not set, it'll raise an exception, but it will be handled by me manually so it won't break the execution of the program.

Is there a way to do the same in Swift?
Using Optionals to simulate an exception won't work, since the performSegueWithIdentifier function returns no value.

Comment: You should not do it that way. The try-catch method in obj-c has a really bad performance, and slows down the whole app. You also should not call performSegueWithIdentifier randomly wait for it to work. Thats really ugly job right there. Call them only when they need to be called.

Comment: have a look at shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: @Thomas I can't see how that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In no imaginable way is `@try`-`@catch`-ing a `performSegueWithIdentifier:` the appropriate approach to this challenge.  Not in Objective-C.  Not in Swift.

Segues can't (or shouldn't) exist independently of storyboards.  After all, if you were try to instantiate a segue, the class name is UI**Storyboard**Segue.  The fact that this class even exists publicly is not so that you can instantiate it and add it at run time.  It exists so that you can subclass the segue, choose your subclass on the storyboard, and set up a segue with custom behavior:

[image]

In Objective-C and Swift, exceptions are reserved for truly exceptional behavior.  Behavior which can be prevented at **development** time.  We should not be relying on `@try`-`@catch` blocks during run-time by the time we've released our app.  We should have fixed our app so that there's nothing to `@catch`.

So with this said, the only way that `performSegueWithIdentifier:` can throw an exception is if the segue identifier we gave it does not exist.  The only reason the segue shouldn't exist is because we made a typo somewhere.

The segues are hooked up and defined at compile time.  There is no public mechanism for checking whether or not a particular segue exists because we just shouldn't be doing this at all.

---

Now, with all that said, if we want to dynamically push or modally present a particular view controller at run time, and we can't know at compile time what view controller it will be (or from what view controller we're getting to it from), then we shouldn't be presenting it via a segue.

Instead, we should be using one of the presentation options the [`UIViewController` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/) defines.

Your options are:

- `presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)`
- `showViewController(_:sender:)`
- `showDetailViewController(_:sender:)`

And in place of an unwind segue, you'd want something like this:

- `dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)`

Comment: Thank you for reply and explanation.
I've seen this idea online in a code for menu controller, so i thought about using it in my project, but needed to translate it in swift. 
Seeing how everybody in unison tells me that this is a wrong use for @try-@catch, and misuse of segues, i started to question this idea and i looked deeper into the code that i'm trying to copy and afterwards i decided to abandon it.

Comment: I slightly disagree with your reasoning. And a good example which I would use to argue is the DrawerController, which supports both left and right drawers. If you want to extend it to be usable in storyboards you need to add support for 3 segues: left, centre and right. However, not everyone needs a right controller. Therefore, if a DrawerController is setup via storyboards left or right segue can be missing (and this is an appropriate behaviour). What would you do in this case?